# How difficult would it be for a Hacker to get into a BitLocker To Go drive?

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

I have a USB Drive protected with BitLocker To Go. I used a User PIN and printed a Recovery Password. I have since lost the Recovery Password and can't remember the PIN.

Is there an efficient way to brute force or otherwise compromise the encryption of the drive?

Comment: The encryption can easily be compromised.... just find the piece of paper you printed the password on. Check under your keyboard or your mouse pad.

Comment: All jokes aside, you should probably never print your passwords for this exact reason. There are plenty of free password storage programs out there. I use one called KeePass.

Answer (score 4):

BitLocker To Go is AES 256-bit encrypted. Your PIN is salted. With current computing power it would take more time than has passed since the [Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) to hack into your drive.

I'm sure you were expecting this answer, as what good would encryption be if you could just hack into it.

Side Note: You can't use TPM on BitLocker To Go. You should treat recover passwords with care, so as to not lose them. You can add recovery keys (files) to BitLocker encrypted drives too.